# "from keyword not found", using distinct in subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

Basically what I want to do is to insert into a table named `tempRecargaBIFINAL` the values `NUM_ORIGEN`, and the sum of case.

When I execute with just `NUM_ORIGEN` run perfect, but when I add the SUM, it show the error listed in the title. Now show the error ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

```
Insert into SAC_IND.tempRecargaBIFINAL(NUM_ORIGEN,REC_A)
WITH
data AS
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT( NUM_ORIGEN ),
       sum(
           case
               when IDPERIODO = (2016010-5)
               then CTA_PRINCIPAL_DELTA else 0 
           end) rec_a x
    from FT_RECARGA_BI
    Where IDPERIODO BETWEEN 201604 and 2016010
    )

Select x from data
Group By x;
```

Following the suggestions i change the query now it

```
Insert into SAC_IND.tempRecargaBIFINAL(NUM_ORIGEN,REC_A)
WITH
data AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT( NUM_ORIGEN )x,
sum(case when IDPERIODO = (2016010-5) then CTA_PRINCIPAL_DELTA else 0 end)rec_a from FT_RECARGA_BI
Where IDPERIODO BETWEEN 201604 and 2016010
)
Select x,rec_a from data
Group By x,rec_a;
```

Finally the query work, i almost cry but the Count give 0, but hey! at last the script work :D

```
Insert into SAC_IND.tempRecargaBIFINAL(NUM_ORIGEN,REC_A)
WITH
data AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT( NUM_ORIGEN ) x,
sum(case when IDPERIODO = (2016010-5) then CTA_PRINCIPAL_DELTA else 0  end)rec_a from FT_RECARGA_BI
Where IDPERIODO BETWEEN 201604 and 2016010
Group by IDPERIODO,NUM_ORIGEN
)
Select x,rec_a from data
Group By x,rec_a;
```

Comment: Pick `rec_a` or `x` as alias, not both.

Comment: `distinct` is **NOT** a function. It always applies to **all** columns in the select list. Writing `distinct (num_origen), ...` is _exactly_ the same thing as `distinct num_origen, ...`

Comment: What is IDPERIODO = (2016010-5)? 2016005

Comment: The `with` keyword and subsequent subquery it making this task more complicated than necessary.

Comment: I change the alias, thanks for that detail, the error change to ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: Inside your CTE, Your SUM function has no GROUP BY, so you get that `ORA-00937` error. And you INSERT INTO table with **2** columns but you only SELECT **1** column (SELECT x FROM...)

Comment: Insert into SAC_IND.tempRecargaBIFINAL(NUM_ORIGEN,REC_A)
WITH
data AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT( NUM_ORIGEN ) x,
sum(case when IDPERIODO = (2016010-5) then CTA_PRINCIPAL_DELTA else 0  end)rec_a from FT_RECARGA_BI
Where IDPERIODO BETWEEN 201604 and 2016010
Group by IDPERIODO,NUM_ORIGEN
)
Select x,rec_a from data
Group By x,rec_a;

Comment: you should've put your answer in the Answer box not by editing your post and putting it there.

Comment: Your solution looks quite confused with a group on an already distinct set of columns and the superfluous parentheses around num_origen. It's mainly a union of sums per num_origin for 2016005 and a zero for every num_origin for the other ids. This is what you were after? You may want to recheck this.

Comment: "but the Count give 0". What count?

Answer (score 0):

You have put IDPERIODO in group by clause while you are using it inside aggregate function sum. So what happens that it sums up  CTA_PRINCIPAL_DELTA  for every IDPERIODO and NUM_ORIGEN.

So query can be two ways

1..

```
Insert into SAC_IND.tempRecargaBIFINAL(NUM_ORIGEN,REC_A)
WITH
data AS
(
SELECT distinct  NUM_ORIGEN  x, IDPERIODO ,
sum (case when IDPERIODO = (2016010-5) then CTA_PRINCIPAL_DELTA else 0  end) rec_a from FT_RECARGA_BI
Where IDPERIODO BETWEEN 201604 and 2016010
Group by IDPERIODO ,NUM_ORIGEN
)
Select x,rec_a from data
Group By x,rec_a;
```

or
2.

```
Insert into SAC_IND.tempRecargaBIFINAL(NUM_ORIGEN,REC_A)
WITH
data AS
(
SELECT distinct NUM_ORIGEN x, 
sum (case when IDPERIODO = (2016010-5) then CTA_PRINCIPAL_DELTA else 0  end) rec_a from FT_RECARGA_BI
Where IDPERIODO BETWEEN 201604 and 2016010
Group by NUM_ORIGEN
)
Select x,rec_a from data
Group By x,rec_a;
```